# Deconstructing a C# Windows Forms application

Tags: c#, winforms

I am browsing an EMGU application built using Windows Forms.  The controls in the application are as follows:

[image]

I would like to simplify the application down to using fewer image boxes.  But when I click on a splitcontainer control, it is selected but I can neither move it around nor even delete it.

How can I break the application down where I can understand what is going on wrt the panels and splitcontainers?

(PS: Not tagging this with EMGU as I don't believe this is an EMGU-specific question.)

Comment: do you have the source of the application? Can you open the project and view the form in designer?

Comment: @kennyzx Yes, I have the application running in Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: so you mean you can select the splitContainer in designer but can't not delete it (via the Delete key)?

Comment: @kennyzx Correct.  When I say "select", I mean that the VS Properties panel starts showing that control.

Comment: If you can't move it, maybe it has Dock=Fill If it can't be properly selected, what gets selected when you click?

Comment: @TaW Just checked and yes, it does have "Fill" specified for it.  Is this what I should be focusing on? Thanks.

Comment: Well, I don't know just what you are planning to do. Four is not such a huge number, so I don't know what you want to simplify. - Nor do I understand why you can't delete the control. Also, you should be able to move it, just not __inside__ the splitpanel because it __fills__ it.. Setting Dock=None will allow you to size and move it inside.

Comment: if you try to click on the splitContainer to select it, the designer is awkwardly focusing on its child panels, instead of the whole splitcontainer, you need to choose it from context menu, that is what the OP is facing with. @TaW

Comment: _the designer is awkwardly focusing on its child panels, instead of the whole splitcontainer_ Hehe. It always does that and therefore the first thing I do is to make the splitterWidth broader: 7 pixels works so much better! One can set the runtime width in code, but for the designer I just don't have the patience to fiddle for the splitter..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still not certain about your issue. I give the steps I use to delete `SplitContainer` from a form:

1. Right click on the `SplitContainer`, and choose "Select splitContainerName".
2. Move its child controls out of it. If its `Dock` is `Fill`, set it as none, so you can resize it, and move its child controls to the empty space of the form.
3. Right click on the SplitContainer, and choose "select splitContainerName" again.
4. Delete the selected `SplitContainer`.

Comment: Yes, setting `Dock` to `None` allows me to move the content around.  This will get me started, thank you.